# Using Applescript or Automator to edit a calendar to move "bump" all events forward one day

Tags: macos, calendar, applescript, schedule, automator

I want to be able to move all events within my mac calendar up one day, ideally with the ability to exclude weekends.

Use Case:  A training program had 10 weeks of daily sessions.  The calendar is uploaded via csv edited for start days and skipped days.  If one were to miss a day they were able to simple push all the events forward one day.

I have looked at Automator and there doesn't appear to be a simple way to set this up with the exception of possibly a folder action option.

Anyone ever do something like this?

Answer (score -1):

I'd be careful about AppleScripting *Calendar.app* in Catalina onwards, as it's now extremely buggy and very easy to incur data loss when something goes wrong.

However, a non-scripting solution would be to cut and paste the events whilst viewing them in *Month* view:

1. Select all the events that you wish to bring forward, which is best done starting with the last, so you end up at the first;

   <sup>If you deselect all other calendars so that the only events visible are the ones in your training programme (I presume these are stored in their own calendar, right...?!), then you can <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to *Select All*, being careful to **deselect** the ones that overlap from the previous month or into the next month.  Individual events are selected/deselected by holding down <kbd>⌘</kbd> and clicking the event.</sup>
2. Hit <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> to *Cut* them to the clipboard;
3. Use the mouse to single-click the day previous to one that contained the first event;
4. Hit <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> to *Paste* the events, the first of which will be pasted into the day that you clicked in step ⓷, with the remaining events repositioned by the same relative amount as was the first.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I apprecaite your taking the time to reply.  While this would work within a month, it doesn't appear to work for selecting things outside of month, and moving month to month may lead to a jumble.  And for weekends I'd have to move everything forward again event by event did find a toolkit for google calendar that is a paid option that does this.  Or may I'll try the folder option.